# Notify reviewers that a post is in multiple queues, and possibly allow them to switch which queue to work on for a post

Tags: feature-request, review

After reviewing a post in one queue (such as Low Quality Posts), the post is dropped from other queues (such as First Posts) for that user. This is okay, but it's somewhat confusing to see other queues' sizes decrease when you refresh the review page. There's also a couple of cases where you might want the controls of one queue when you see a post in another - maybe you find something in the Low Quality Posts queue that happens to be a first post, and you would therefore like to use an auto-comment from the First Post queue instead of just flagging it (or at least leave a "manual" comment where you might not have otherwise).

The feature reqeust is this: Under the bar that states the post's reason for being in the queue and shows the action buttons, add another bar that says something to the effect of:

> This post is also in the Close Votes queue because it has recent close votes.
>   This post is also in the First Posts queue because it was made by a new user.
>   This post is also in the Late Answers queue because it was posted to an old question.
>   This post is also in the Low Quality Posts queue because of its length and content.
>   etc.

In addition, it would be nice to have the ability to click somewhere in this bar to switch which queue you're operating on for this post (and therefore which action buttons you have access to), or even have all the buttons for the relevant queues visible by default (though maybe de-emphasized). This is somewhat of a narrow use-case but doesn't seem too difficult (am probably wrong).

Comment: I have noticed this as well - perhaps someone has a technique how to effectively prioritise the reviewing process.